# How do I type a “confused word”?

Tags: fonts

I want to know how to type something like this: T̸̡̺͉͈̘̩̺̉ͩͧ̿̉̊̾̓ͥ̎̍ͨ͂ͩ͂̂ͩͮ͘͟͢ḧ̵͍̦͉͎̙̦̘͎̜̜͔͓̦́̑̒͊ͩ̎ͫ̏̊ͫ̊̏ͣ͂ͤͥ̓͛̋͘͝i̴̶͛̀͐͑̑ͮͭ̄ͪͦͮ̀ͧ͗ͬ̏҉͔̙̻̤͙̤͚̺̬̟̙̣̘̯̟̮̮ş̷̖͎̹̺̫̭̞̖͙̼̞̺̩̬̹̜̗̪̭͌̌̽̇͐ͤ̈̒͑̚͢͜ ̴̨̩̹̟̖͓͙͓̮͙̦͖̭̭̹͔̳͚̖̍̎ͦ͋ͩ̏̓i̵̧̟̜̪͈̬̪̘̲͖͕̣̼̠͚͙̓͛̓̅ͫ̒̾͋̑̊͆̉͌͛̚ͅͅș̛̛̠̭͈͇ͯͥ́ͬͦ̊͑̂ͣ̐̀ͩ̋ͥ̃͒̑̾͆ ̤̪̱̩̫͖̯̰̬ͣ̋̓̅̃̍ͫ̊ͮͧͩ͠͞s̰̝̟̹͉̫͚̝̬̙͔͚̠͓̥̊̆͆̃͑͛͊̈́ͪͪ̄ͧ̾̍̎͌̕͘͘͡ơ̶̛̼̪̰̭̾̆͗̾ͧͫ̅̎͛̽́̈ͦ̀̔̚̚͜ͅm̢̧̨̲͕̙͉̩͚̱̮̩̪̳̀ͬͣ̊ͯͯͣ́͐̅ͫ̍͋͑͜e̾̿̉̈́̈́̉́̄҉̷̢͍̟̫̖̜̝̪̥̺͖͉̖̭͕͢ͅ ̖̜̲̺̪̱̦̙̗̞͈̺͙͕̯̈́ͪ̊ͫ͊ͧ͐̑̾̊ͭ͊ͥ̎̌̒͟͟͞͡ͅc̣̥͇̺͓̣̼̼͇̰͉̬̺͖ͤ̍̅̈̅ͨͧ̄̅͋͌̋ͩ̔ͣͫͦͫ͢͠͝o̴̳̰̳̣̺̮̯͕͚̬̹̫̮ͭ̿̍ͥ͂͆̾̉̄̇ͧͧ̓ͬ͝ͅo͐̌ͬ͋͌ͥ̾̍̆̍̔̐͌͏̷͏̷̧͎̺̦̦͓͙̝͎͙͚̜̻l̴̦̩̝̻͈̳̩̤̝̰͉̻̥̖̙͎̞̬ͤ̈ͬ͌̀͊̍͗̅͗ͬ͗̔̽̀ ̵̲̳̹͙͔̙͎̰̹̣͖̦̝͍̺̞͖̃̇̈́͊̊̂̏̿͢ẇ̵̨̧̯͔͈̦̲͔̥̬̖͎̺͍̭̯̝͗̽͑ͬ̎̀ͭͯ̀͋̿̓̒̀̚͘ͅō̧̩͔̺͓̺͙͚̤̼͍̺̼̤̜͙̪̪͙͎͐̂ͯ̒ͬ̄́͘͝ṛ̵̶͖̲̦̩͈̪͇̺̱̪͖͈̤͋ͯ͗̑͐̍́̚̚͢͟d̶̍́ͬ̅̊̄ͨͩ͘͏҉̵̩̤̲͇̱͔̘͇̻͔̙̩ͅͅs̄͛̀̑̒̽̈̎͐ͬ͐̋ͧ̒̔̀̕͏̩͉͚̼̯̦̫̹

is there any way to do that? is it a font or a latex glitch thing?

To clarify, I want to be able to write with characters that overlay each other and I want the be able to change the text underneath and add more of the weird symbols

Basically I want to type nonsense w/ some form of TeX or LaTeX

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. At least on my computer monitor, your posting is nearyl undecipherable because characters (glyphs?) are densely overlaid and interfere visually both with each other and the few Latin-alphabet characters. Please modify your posting to clarify what you're looking to achieve -- and how this objective might be related to TeX and friends.

Comment: I actually want to achieve the "nearyl undecipherable" text and I want them to interfere with each other, that is actually what I am trying to achieve. Also thx for the welcome

Comment: Sure, just use a font with combining diacritics and start stacking. If the diacritics start colliding, you can manually adjust their vertical position. Without an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Use Code2000 in LuaLaTeX. But I voted for closing as off topic.

Comment: @Kyruem Well, your comment reveals that you're not primarily wanting to know how to do a specific thing with LaTeX ("all I want to do is like be able to type nonsense on, say a Word Doc", so I'm afraid this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Ok, even if this is off topic will I still see replies? Srry, I'm new and I only want this question answred

Comment: Again, sorry, I don't know any website that will answer this, and I do think this is off topic, thx anyways

Comment: Please see my revision, which allows more flexibility.  For what it is worth, I find your question a legitimate one.

Comment: This compiles perfectly with `xelatex` or `lualatex`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\begin{document} 
% paste your Unicode nonsense here
\end{document}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?  EDITED to introduce `\updown`. RE-EDITED to allow it to work with `\normalsize`, by implementing a `\scalefactor` for the gibberish, as well as allowing a stackgap setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\def\scalefactor{.25}
\setstackgap{S}{3pt}
\def\updown#1#2{\def\useanchorwidth{T}\scalebox{\scalefactor}{%
  \stackunder{\stackon{}{\Shortstack{#1}}}{\Shortstack{#2}}}\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
How do I type this 
w\updown{w u \$ \% n O P}{s @ \# f ) +}
o\updown{A R T w u \$ \% n O P}{s @ f ) ) z e R}
r\updown{w u \$ \% P \_ = n O P}{:  @ \# f ) d c}
d\updown{w u \$ \% n O P}{s @ \# f ) P q S \$} 
\ or
\def\scalefactor{.4}%
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}%
w\updown{w u \$ \% n O P}{s @ \# f ) +}
o\updown{A R T w u \$ \% n O P}{s @ f ) ) z e R}
r\updown{w u \$ \% P \_ = n O P}{:  @ \# f ) d c}
d\updown{w u \$ \% n O P}{s @ \# f ) P q S \$}?
\end{document}
```

[image]

More gibberishy things can be obtained with the use of various symbol packages.  For example, the use of `pmboxdraw` with this invocation

```
Or
\def\scalefactor{.3}%
\setstackgap{S}{0pt}%
w\updown{\textSFxxvi{} \textSFl{} 2 \textSFi{} \textlfblock{} \textSFxl}
  {1 2 \textlfblock{} \textSFxl 3 \textSFxxiv{}}
o\updown{:  @ \# f ) d c}{w u \$ \% P \_ = n O P}
r\updown{\textSFxxvi{} \textSFl{} 2 \textSFi{} \textlfblock{} \textSFxl \% \&}
  {1 2 \textSFxl 3 \textSFxxiv{}}
d\updown{\textSFxxvi{} \textSFl{} 2 \textSFi{} \textSFxl + = -}
  {1 2 \textlfblock{} \textSFxl 3 \textSFxxiv{}}
```

looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thx, srry this is "off topic"

Comment: @Kyruem No apologies necessary.  I was happy to help.

Comment: @Kyruem It was not off topic. Sometimes the closing squad is too hasty :) (+1, by the way, Steven).